# How to run vba macros on xlsm docs with IRM Sensitivity Labels applied

Tags: excel, vba, azure

Azure Rights Management was recently implemented in the company, allowing to tag documents with sensitivity labels, and so restrict access to the document contents according to the user.
Excel xlsm templates using protected sheets now vba crash with "Run-time Error '1004'" on any document which has a sensitivity label applied, no matter the type of label, even if the user has access to the doc and is able to edit. The user just does'nt have "Full Control"

Debugging showed that the error occurs at every use of the Sheet.Protect method.
Most of the sheets are password protected, and the method is used on Wb.Open event with the UserInterfaceOnly:=True parameter to allow macros to do their job and display the results.
Templates work fine without any sensitivity label applied, as always did before IRM.

I understand that introduction of the IRM may have introduced some limitations or different uses of the method. But I was unable to find any related documentation on this subject.
This issue is surely affecting most vba programmers/users were IRM has been implemented so there must be a way to overcome this issue without simply removing the sheet protections which would allow users to jeopardize the templates.

Should we ask the IT dpt to include Full Control in the Labels Config (I'm assuming this would be possible)? Are there security issues if the users have Full Control?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why have you not asked your IT department before posting here?

Comment: Reply was: this is a vba issue and should be solved modifying vba code to avoid the Error. Question is how to do it.

Comment: I suppose the introduction of IRM impacted many other people using/developing excel templates with vba. so I assume there must be a solution. Didn't find any MS related docs on the issue.